# Is using this 'ing' word after the comma correct? Why?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

Could someone please explain why or why not this type of sentence is correct?

> The man bent down, his shirt crinkling.

If it is correct, would removing the word 'his' after the comma change that? 
What kind of error or type of sentence would this count as? I tried googling this, along with sentence rules, but never found anything that specified this kind as either wrong or right.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence you provided is correct.

It is a shorter form of:

> The man bent down, <strike>**and**</strike> his shirt <strike>**was**</strike> crinkling.

or:

> The man bent down, <strike>**while**</strike> his shirt <strike>**was**</strike> crinkling.

If you remove "his", the sentence still remains correct, with no real change in meaning.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "his shirt crinkling" is a *participle phrase*, and it serves to describe the man as he bends down.

It would be correct also to remove "his", but then the sentence is less good, because we want to say that it is the man's shirt that crinkles. Using "his" as a determiner tells us which shirt